# On how many devices can I test an IPhone application

Tags: iphone, testing, deployment

I am currently developping an IPhone application and will need to test it soon. We have 4 testers in our clients office plus me.

So I would like to know if I can test an IPhone application on 5 different devices or if there is a limit. 
If there is, what is this limit?

Regards,

Comment: In case you haven't, remember you need to pay $99 to Apple to become a registered developer, test on devices and release to the app store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device limit for ad-hoc testing your app currently stands at 100 devices. So you'll be well within the limit.